# jqGrid colModel persists to server but trigger reloadGrid fails to put data in right columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, dataset

**Question in a nutshell**

### With each column tweak, I save the new column model to the server, for that user, and immediately start mutating the JSON to align with the new column order for that user's ajax requests. In this scenario, do I still need the remapColumns function or the permuatation variable?

My initial jQGrid (4.4.5) is loaded using datatype:'json', loadonce:true (fwiw)

The server explicitly writes out the javascript variables to properly initialize the grid's colNames and colModel in the desired order, width and desired 'hidden-ness' - unique to that users' last saved settings (if any). For example:

```
var MainTableColumnNames = ['Work Order','DatePickedUp','Generator','Order Status'];
var MainTableColumnModel = [
{name: 'Work Order', index: 'Work Order', editable:false, align: 'left', hidden:false, width:82 },
{name: 'DatePickedUp', index: 'DatePickedUp', editable:false, align: 'left', hidden:false, formatter:'date', width:120 },
{name: 'Generator', index: 'Generator', editable:false, align: 'left', hidden:false, width:264 }, width:293 },
{name: 'Order Status', index: 'Order Status', editable:false, align: 'left', hidden:false, width:50 }
        ];
```

I have my own method for saving col model data to the server and am not using any of the concepts that I've run across recently (it seems Oleg has addressed this a lot). FWIW: I only save width,size,hidden (and the column layout order is implied). Thus, some of the above col model is supplied from user settings, while other parts are derived from defaults or by reflecting on properties of the .NET System.Data.DataColumn

Furthermore, the resizeStop event and the extended column chooser both point to a common script function which persists changes in the column layout. Thus, the next time the user loads the web page, everything will be laid out according to the new settings saved for that user. That is all working fine.

But.. even before they reload the web page, any new requests to the server will now be sending the json data back to the user in the new column order. And, I am not sure what is going wrong. The column sorting issue that I've seen others refer to elsewhere on StackOverflow is not happening to me.. you can click a column header and the data re-sorts in place (I presume it is because I use loadonce, so it sorts using existing localdata).

But, if I click on a node in my tree control (i have my own tree implementation that loads various slices of data into the main grid) the new JSON data coming back is not successfully loading into jqGrid-  a couple of columns look transposed -

Now if I do a full page refresh everything is fine.

An example of how I get new data into the grid, say, when we click one of my tree nodes:

```
$('#myCustomTreeNode').bind('tree.click', function(event){
   var node = event.node;

   var newUrl = '/api/DataView/MainGrid/' + node.id;

   $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{url : newUrl, datatype: 'json', postData: { 'guid':someVariable} }).trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

***Update: So here's my question:***

So, my main question is: after updating a jqGrid column model (not only jqGrid's client model, but when the successive server-supplied data will immediately conform to the new column order).. I want to know the proper way to continue using the current instantiated jqGrid instance w/o a full page re-draw. Must I do a full GridUnload or GridDestroy? I'm hoping someone can give me pointers on something I must be doing wrong with my .trigger 'reloadGrid' call illustrated above.

***More detail***
As stated in my opening paragraph, each user has their own "MainTableColumnModel" variable written to their browser session.. literally on page draw, the physical column order is written in the order of their last saved column permutation.

*And, I think this is where I am possibly getting things wrong.*

In other examples [like this one by Oleg](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage.htm) it seems all users should be getting the same initial column model, and if they've saved a specific model into their user settings, then I should be loading up that as a permutation variable for remapColumns to process when the page intially loads, rather than transforming all the JSON data requests according to each users' individual column-model setting.

Since I've got my alternate method almost working, I'm still hoping I can get this right.

Comment: Bottom line - what's your question?

Comment: @DevlshOne - sorry it wasn't clear. See update above.

Comment: sorry, but you don't posted any implementation code, so it's difficult to understand your question. You wrote for example "I save the new column model to the server". Do you really save the whole `colModel` as the users settings? In the case by the way you would don't have any problem with : `remapColumns` method, called is the user change the column order, resort items in `colModel`. So the *current* order of items in `colModel` corresponds the users settings. So one can't really help you if you don't posted more details. If you really save `colModel` then how you can modify it?

Comment: From the small code fragment which you posted one sees one real problem: the usage of spaces in column names (like `name: 'Order Status'`). You should interpret `name` property as the name of variable or the name of property of some object. You should not use meta-characters (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) inside of `name` property. Another remark: one have to have the same `index` and `name` properties in case of `loadonce:true`. So it's better just remove `index` from the column model. In the case the `index` and `name` properties will be always the same.

Comment: @Oleg: Very useful tidbits - I'll make adjustments. I only persist column order, hidden=true/false, and column widths. The server, per request, refers to the latest column order saved in user settings and mutates the JSON accordingly.

Comment: @Oleg When I started to abandon my 'server-mutates-everything/client-mutates-nothing' approach, and started moving toward [your localstorage demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage.htm), I was still trying to use my server's model to generate the initial perm array that would be written out as a js variable. It was not quite right- I think I was ignoring the 'rn' column completely, so, I think my array was one slot short. I do show row numbers on my grid and so 'rn' is visible and was getting weirdly moved around in my grid.

Comment: @Oleg -I've been using jqGrid for a while now and thought one of it's 'features' (from my general usage) was how well it handled my existing System.Data.DataTables which have column names (straight from SQL server fill adapter) which feature spaces. Are you aware of use-case scenarios where spaces in the colModel.name make jqGrid throw errors?